# My model doesn't export as seen in blender

Tags: 3d-view, export, faces

When i see my model in blender (both solid mode and rendered mode) it appears with no problem,
But when i export it (fbx obj or dae) it has some kind of deformation.

More info :

- I have no texture (only assigned materials to faces)
- I did not used any other workspace other than layout(default workspace)
- I did not used any other mode other than edit mode and object mode.
- I did not used any modifiers on this model
- There are no other models in this scene(not even hided ones)
- I checked for overlapping faces there are none.
- There are 1397 vertices and 2790 triangles

[image: problemPreview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kind *OpenVFX : The Blender Community* member *AmyLynx#7602* we have solved the problem.

The main problem was i have had so much vertices on individual faces.
Solved with Triangulate Modifier.

- Before :
  [image: Before]
- After : [image: After]